# File output in java not working

Tags: java

so my homework is to create a parking lot simulator which receives queries from an input.txt file which are passed as an array of JSON objects which contain a String query and an int parkingID. For each of those queries i am required to do perform an action. When i try to output the information to a file nothing happens. Could you take a look at what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
```

Here is the main function

```
public class Company{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 


        String content = new 
String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.txt")));
        Gson gson= new GsonBuilder().create();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Query>>() {}.getType();
        List<Query> queries = gson.fromJson(content,listType);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        ParkingLot[] array = new ParkingLot[10]; 
        array[0] = new ParkingLot(0);

        int counter = 1;

       for(int i =0; i < queries.size(); i++)
        {
           try{
               String query = queries.get(i).getQuery();
             int queryParkingID = queries.get(i).getParkingID();

                   if(query.equals("car entered"))
                   {
                       array[queryParkingID].carEntered();
                   }
                   else if(query.equals("car left"))
                   {
                       array[queryParkingID].carLeft();
                   }
                   else if(query.equals("Parking lot opened"))
                   {
                       array[counter] = new ParkingLot(counter);
                       counter++;
                   }

               }

            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println(e);
                 String query = queries.get(i).getQuery();
                 int queryParkingID = queries.get(i).getParkingID();
                if (queryParkingID == -1)
                   {
                       if(query.equals("bandwidth"))
                       {
                           out.println(array[queryParkingID].getBandwidth());
                       }
                       else if(query.equals("bandwidth all"))
                       {
                           out.println(ParkingLot.bandwidthAll);
                       }
                       else if(query.equals("parked"))
                       {
                           out.println(array[queryParkingID].getCarsParked());
                       }
                       else if(query.equals("parked all"))
                       {
                           out.println(ParkingLot.carsParkedAll);
                       }
                       else if(query.equals("revenue"))
                       {
                           out.println(array[queryParkingID].getRevenue());
                       }
                       else if(query.equals("revenue all"))
                       {
                           out.println(ParkingLot.revenueAll);
                       }
                   }
                }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                  System.out.println(e);
                    }

            catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e);
                }


        }
     out.close();
    }     



   }
```

This is the Query function used to store queries

```
class Query {

        private int parkingID ;
        private String query;

       public String getQuery()
        {
            return query;
        }

        public int getParkingID()
        {
            return parkingID;

}}
```

And here is the parking lot class

```
public class ParkingLot {

private int parkingID;
private static int parkingFee = 5;
private static int maxCarCapacity = 30;
private int revenue;
private int carsParked;
static int carsParkedAll;
static int revenueAll;
private int bandwidth;
static int bandwidthAll;

public ParkingLot(int parkingID) 
{
    this.parkingID = parkingID;
    revenue = 0;
    carsParked = 0;
    carsParkedAll = 0;
}
public void carEntered()
{
    if(carsParked < maxCarCapacity )
    {

    revenue += parkingFee;
    revenueAll += parkingFee;
    carsParked++;
    carsParkedAll++; 
    bandwidth++;
    bandwidthAll++;
    }   
}
public void carLeft()
{
    if(carsParked > 0)
    {   
    carsParked--; 
    carsParkedAll--; 
    }
}   
public int getCarsParkedAll() {
        return carsParkedAll;
    }

public int getRevenueAll() {
        return revenueAll;
    }

public int getBandwidth() {
        return bandwidth;
    }
public void setBandwidth(int bandwidth) {
        this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
    }
public int getBandwidthAll() {
        return bandwidthAll;
    }

public static int getParkingFee() {
    return parkingFee;
}
public static void setParkingFee(int parkingFee) {
    ParkingLot.parkingFee = parkingFee;
}


public int getParkingID() {
    return parkingID;
}
public void setParkingID(int parkingID) {
    this.parkingID = parkingID;
}


public int getMaxCarCapacity() {
    return maxCarCapacity;
}
public void setMaxCarCapacity(int maxCarCapacity) {
    ParkingLot.maxCarCapacity = maxCarCapacity;
}


public int getRevenue() {
    return revenue;
}
public void setRevenue(int revenue) {
    this.revenue = revenue;
}

public int getCarsParked() {
    return carsParked;
}
public void setCarsParked(int carsParked) {
    this.carsParked = carsParked;
}




}
```

And here is an example of a query

```
 {"parkingID":-3,"query":"bandwidth"}
```

We also have to handle exceptions so I had to move the out part into the catch block so it can print out when it reaches an out of bounds exception.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is not clear what that code should do, it is way to long to follow. But you write to out only in a exception catch handler, that can't be right.

Comment: It's because the out of bounds exception catches -1 and its used in that exception to output the data. despite that it still does not work even if it is not in a catch block

Comment: Since `PrintWiter` generally is known to work, the problem is I guess in the if block. You can do debugging with a debugger or by adding printfs.